# How can i use custom created table (in function) in recursive calling by reference

Tags: oracle

I'm creating a function that should recursively go through the tree structure in database and in each iteration i have to count capacities (some numbers => not important) and add a new row to table which is not present in database. That means that the table was initialized in calling function and passed by reference.

```sql
create or replace TYPE myTableRow AS object (
  OP varchar2(50),
  VP varchar2(50),
  CisloP varchar2(50),
  Tp float,
  Tj float,
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION myTableRow
 RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);


create or replace TYPE myTable AS TABLE OF myTableRow;
```

So as you can see i have created type for row and table type from rows.

But here is the deal.. I have 2 functions. In first i'm declaring and constructing the table

```sql
RETURN myTable IS -- just a snippet...
  rozpad myTable;
  vyrobek varchar2(50);
BEGIN
  rozpad := myTable();
```

This function should return whole table... and this table is passed to another function (procedure) which will do the recursion

```sql
RozpadKusovnik_pomocna(artikel_numer, rozpad, 1, OP_num, artikel_numer);
```

and there i just don't know how to insert a row or create (initialize/allocate) a new one. I have a loop where i want to insert rows in table and then call the same function again with different parameters and pass the same table by reference, so that i will have a whole table when i'm out of recursion..

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE RozpadKusovnik_pomocna(artikel_numer IN VARCHAR2, inputTable IN OUT myTable, mnozstvi IN FLOAT, OP_num IN VARCHAR2, VP_num IN VARCHAR2)
.
.
.
  LOOP
    insert into inputTable values myTableRow(OP_num, VP_num, PAPP.BELEGUNGSEINHEIT_NR, RUESTZEIT, ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT);
  END LOOP;
```

And last question is.. How can i use this table after that. Will it work like a regular table for the time of executing? So i can join it and do group by after that? Or should i create a table and after every execution remove all data?

Error(14,17): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view not exist => this is the insert part

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do operation like group by and other table operations then I would suggest you to use `GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE`.

They is session specific tables and data will be seen only in your session. Also, you will not have to delete the data after usage as it will be wiped out once session is closed.

You can refer oracle documentation for more information on it.

Cheers!!

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the question as the OP is not talking about inserting into a database table but is trying to append an object to a collection.

Comment: OP asked for suggestions that which will be the better option in last few lines of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to insert into a table. You are trying to grow a collection (`inputTable`) and then put a new value into it. To do this `EXTEND` the collection and then insert a new `myTableRow` element into the last index:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE RozpadKusovnik_pomocna(
  artikel_numer IN     VARCHAR2,
  inputTable    IN OUT myTable,
  mnozstvi      IN     FLOAT,
  OP_num        IN     VARCHAR2,
  VP_num        IN     VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
  inputTable.EXTEND(1);
  inputTable( inputTable.COUNT ) := myTableRow(OP_num, VP_num, PAPP.BELEGUNGSEINHEIT_NR, RUESTZEIT, ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT);
END;
```

> Will it work like a regular table for the time of executing?

No, it is not a table; it is a collection data type.

> So i can join it and do group by after that?

You can append items to the collection and delete items using PL/SQL in procedures. You can also use `MULTISET` operators in SQL to union/intersect collections.

You can perform SQL operations using the collection with a table collection expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE( inputTable )
```

That would allow you to perform `GROUP BY` queries on the collection's data or to `JOIN` it to other tables persisted in the database (or collections via table collection expressions).

> Or should I create a table and after every execution remove all data?

If the procedure is run twice at the same time then you will have two procedures appending data to / clearing data from the same database table at the same time and may have concurrency issues.

Comment: So this: ```create or replace TYPE myTable AS TABLE OF myTableRow;``` is creating just a collection of composite data type which i have also created... so i have to extend it (allocate another row) and insert in desired position by row index? Well thank you for answer. Really alot.. And if i call the function like you said TABLE(function(...)) where function is returning myTable, i can use it like a table when it's being executed... Last part is: ```PROCEDURE RozpadKusovnik_pomocna ``` is recursive so it's calling itself. Will there be a problem with concurrency? @MT0